Computational efficient multiplication involing Toeplitz matrix
I have a question regarding Toeplitz matrix. Suppose I have a hermitian Toeplitz matrix $\textbf{T}$ and a DFT matrix $\textbf{F}$. I do not have access directly to $\textbf{T}$ but a matrix $\textbf{M}=\textbf{F}^H\textbf{T}\textbf{F}$. I would like to recover $\textbf{T}$ from $\textbf{M}$ with the less computational complexity. It is clear we can apply multiply left and right by the DFT matrix so we can use the FFT to compute $\textbf{T}$ in $2N^2\log(N)$ where $N$ is the size of $\textbf{T}$. But, can we lower that complexity?
My first try was using a circulant/skew-circulant decomposition of the Toeplitz matrix $\textbf{T}$ but that approach led me to nowhere. I assume it should be related with the fact the Toeplitz matrix is completely determined by the first row however I could not find anything to use that property.
Best regards.
